# ansible playbook error even for small space

Tags: ansible

I have just stated using ansible on Linux environment and I am really unable to understand the syntax in playbook yml

for example, I am writing simple play book to install/uninstall the packages.

Just with small space in yum module line 5

### Working play book

```
---
- hosts: test,dev
  tasks:
  - name: install/uninstall package httpd
    yum: name=httpd state=removed
```

### result

```
[root@rhel7m100 krishnp]# ansible-playbook package-httpd-installation.yml --check

PLAY [test,dev] **********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel7c1]
ok: [rhel6c2]
ok: [rhel6c1]

TASK [install/uninstall package httpd] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel6c2]
ok: [rhel6c1]
ok: [rhel7c1]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
rhel6c1                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
rhel6c2                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
rhel7c1                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

### Error play book

```
---
- hosts: test,dev
  tasks:
  - name: install/uninstall package httpd
     yum: name=httpd state=removed        ---> the only difference is the small
                                               space in from of yum command
```

### result

```
[root@rhel7m100 krishnp]# ansible-playbook package-httpd-installation.yml --check
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/krishnp/package-httpd-installation.yml': line 5, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - name: install/uninstall package httpd
     yum: name=httpd state=removed
        ^ here

enter code hereexception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: mapping values are not allowed in this context
  in "<unicode string>", line 5, column 9
```

---

Does it really matter that small space will make trouble for playbook to run?

Comment: One of the main features of YAML sintax is to make it easy to read, identation is really important and you will have problem with your playbooks if you don't respect it... One other important recomendation is to use spaces, not tabs.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it really matter that small space will make trouble for playbook to run?

Yes. Playbooks are written in [YAML](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html). And YAML is very strict about indentation, because you usually "switch context" with different indentation.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, space matters a lot in YAML, as it strictly uses space character as indent

Here are few more basic rules with YAML syntax.

### YAML Basics Rules

- Applicable YAML files: all files with a `.yml` extension.
- Tabs are NOT allowed, use spaces ONLY.
- You MUST indent your code with 1 or more spaces.
- All keys/properties are case-sensitive.